# get RowIndex of Grid from a checkbox

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the row index of my checkbox, the current code i can get the checked value of the checkbox. the closest doesn't work and i'm stack.
If i check a box on grid row 1 an alert should shows 1

```
        $(":checkbox").change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                var id = $(this).closest("tr");

                alert(id.innerText);


            } else {
                alert("Failed");
            }
        });
```

EDIT:
iv'e added this line

```
var $id = $(this).closest("tr");
   alert($id.index() + 1)
   var table = document.getElementById("tblSearchLogs");
   var appid = table.rows[$id].cells[1].innerText
```

But it gives me an error

> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'cells'
>   of undefined or null reference

TABLE DIV

```
  <div class="row" style="margin-top: 1em;">
            <div  class="table-responsive">
                <table id="tblSearchLogs" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>

                        <tr >
                            <th style="width: 5%; font-weight:bold"> </th>
                            <th style="width: 10%; font-weight:bold">No.</th>
                            <th style="width: 30%; font-weight:bold">App ID</th>
                            <th style="width: 30%; font-weight:bold">Name</th>
                            <th style="width: 40%; font-weight:bold">Date of Birth</th>


                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                        @{
                            if (Model != null)
                            {
                                int x = 1;
                                foreach (xxxx.Models.Class.Listxx ldx in Model.searchlist)
                                {

                                    <tr>
                                        <td> <input type="checkbox" class="divChckBox"/> </td>
                                        <td>@x </td>
                                        <td id="appid">@ldx.AppID</td>
                                        <td>@ldx.Name </td>
                                        <td>@ldx.DOB</td>



                                    </tr>
                                    x++;
                                }

                            }

                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`InnerText` is for getting and setting text property of element. Also its not working here as you are calling it on jquery object of element and not DOM element.

You need to use index of element here:

```
 var $id = $(this).closest("tr");
 alert($id.index() + 1); // as index starts from 0
```

Comment: you got an idea with this 
  $(":checkbox").change(function () {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    var $id = $(this).closest("tr");
                    var table = document.getElementById("tblSearchLogs");
                    var appid = table.rows[$id].cells[1].innerText
                    alert(appid)
                } else {
                    alert("Failed")
                }
            });

It gives an error of

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'cells' of undefined or null reference

Comment: Can you post it as new question?

Comment: post on the 90 mins.. :(

Comment: can you share the rendered html

Comment: where is the HTML?

Comment: Editted it again..will this do?

Comment: try this `$id[0].cells[0].innerText` instead of `table.rows[$id].cells[1].innerText`

Comment: it work.. just was confused.. why $id[0]?.. not $id[$id.index() + 1]

Comment: `$id[0]` --> Dom object of tr


`cells[0]` --> get first td. as index are 0 based